# Flutter not printing / debugPrinting / logging and ignoring breakpoints since catalina update

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Since upgrading to macOS Catalina, Flutter does not log anything anymore.
I am using VS Code with the Flutter extension. It doesn't matter whether I run it via the Visual Studio Code extension or with `flutter run`.

Neither `print` nor `debugPrint` nor `developer.log` produce any output.

Just in case, inside my widget's build method at the very top:

```dart
developer.log('log me', name: 'my.app.category');
print("log me");
debugPrint("log me");
```

Does not do anything. Setting breakpoints in VS Code is also completely ignored. I guess this has to do with the upgrade to Catalina but I have no clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug that seems to affect physical devices running iOS 13, reported at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41133. A Flutter contributor there explains:

> This is related to [#40448](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40448). This isn't a regression in Flutter, but rather that something changed in iOS 13 that we are no longer able to read logs. I worked around this in that issue by using mDNS to discover the app observatory, but we still need to fix the lack of logs.

According to the issue, it was fixed by https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/43915, which is now released on the stable channel.